# how fix imports using a netbeans plugin /api

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I'm developing a NetBeans extension/plugin. Now I want to fix imports programmatically. I used robot class and simulate keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> which is shortcut for `fix imports`. It works but there are some problems.for example need to focus editor panel then i have to bring it to font and wait .sometimes i have to steal the focus .and since it's a extension it can internally access feathers if i do that kind of simulation i really don't need a extension. So how can I internally fix imports from NetBeans extension for Java class?

I read both [faq](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ) site and [development javadoc](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/) but I couldn't found any thing related to fix import option.

Comment: I am not extension/plugin developer, but "*It works but there are problems*." sounds vague. Maybe it is worth describing your problem in more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran out of time before I actually got this to work but hopefully this will help.

The class I think you want is `org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.imports.JavaFixAllImports`

There are a number of methods in there that look promising if you have the right references.

In order to use it you need your module to depend on the `Java Editor` module which does NOT publicly export any of its packages. So to use it you need to click the `Show NON-API Modules` checkbox in the Add Modules dialog, and then you need to edit the module dependency and select the `Implementation Version` radio button and make sure the checkbox for `Include Packages in Classpath` is set.

Like this:

[image: Screenshot showing how to edit module dependancies]

You can browse the source here:

http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/842027a30807/java.editor/src/org/netbeans/modules/java/editor/imports/JavaFixAllImports.java

It doesn't look like it has much in the way of javadoc comments other than one license and author comment at the beginning.

---

update

thanks to WillShackleford i was able to fiximports from plugin code. if anyone wondering how to fix imports(for java) using netbean plugin.
here is the code.
you should import `org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.imports.JavaFixAllImports`

```
  public void importFix() {
       JavaFixAllImports fiximports = JavaFixAllImports.getDefault();
       jtc = EditorRegistry.lastFocusedComponent();
       FileObject fo = FileUtil.toFileObject(new File("path of the .java file"));
       fiximports.fixAllImports(fo, jtc);
   }
```

Comment: thanks you so much.i never thought i could able to complete my addon. but now i can.thanks you again.

Comment: and one question can we see this class on javadoc http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/ ?? i can't find a node/java there

Comment: thanks you again do you have any idea why i can't import that class? i added java editor to dependencies .but when i write import statement netbeans ask me to search dependencies again and again.see this image http://i.imgur.com/5jOnstx.png and this http://i.imgur.com/8KJt98Q.png

Comment: Having the module added but not having Implementation Version or not having the include in classpath checkbox set will cause it to still fail to find the import.

Comment: it worked  when check Implementation .thanks you so so so much